# Is there an efficient way to write several HTML strings to a PDF document in Java?

Tags: java, html, performance, itext

I am querying an API page to create a PDF of the information on that page. The API pages are parsed into "TestCase" objects first. Many of the field values in the TestCase objects are HTML strings. Is there a time-efficient way to write these HTML strings to a new PDF document?

I'm currently using iTextPDF and their XMLWorkerHelper in order to parse the HTML strings and write them to the PDF document. The issue that I'm running into is that, since there are so many fields that I have to write as individual HTML strings, it takes about 5-6 seconds to do this step for each PDF document, but the rest of the program only takes about 3 or 4 . Even worse, when I export its maven project as a jar, the makePDF step takes 20 seconds for each TestCase object. This step is much slower than anything else (including querying and reading values from the API into the TestCase object). I've tried collecting all of the HTML strings and putting them in one big string to read from in case the issue was that I was creating several instances of the XMLWorkerHelper to write the InputStream made from the HTML strings however this did not speed up that step.

```java
public void makePDF(TestCase tc) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
        document.open();
        List<FieldValue> values = tc.getFieldValues();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i) {
            FieldValue fv = values.get(i);
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(fv.getValue());
            XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);
            document.add(new Paragraph("\n"));
        }
        document.close();
}
```

I still need the HTML strings to print correctly to the PDF document but I'd like to make it take less time if possible. In many cases, I'm feeding in 20 or 30 TestCase objects into this function (in some cases, as many as 500 at a time) so making this process take less time to run is very important since the people using the tool don't want to wait 6 or 7 minutes just to make a few PDFs. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"Even worse, when I export its maven project as a jar, the makePDF step takes 20 seconds for each TestCase object"* - this really sounds weird. I would understand a difference for the first document, but later documents should be approximately as fast as before.

Comment: Anyway, what kind of html strings are we're talking about here? A simple paragraph each? Or complex tables?

Comment: About half of them are simple paragraphs or lists, but there are several with formatted tables with different colored text, fonts, font sizes, etc. All of these things are supposed to be recreated in the PDF exactly as they are on the web page.

Comment: Also, after running it with a test case that has none of the fields set (there are about 35 fields), where the only thing I add to the document is the field name, it still takes 20 seconds to write it all to the document.

Comment: That sounds like the actual problem is _not_ the HTML transformation but something else which merely is executed at about the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment you said

> Also, after running it with a test case that has none of the fields set (there are about 35 fields), where the only thing I add to the document is the field name, it still takes 20 seconds to write it all to the document.

To test this I used the following piece of code (essentially your code with your field values generated just in time and the field count a constant):

```java
int fieldCount = 35;
long start = System.nanoTime();

OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(filename);
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
document.open();
for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; ++i) {
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(("<p>" + "Value " + i + "</p>").getBytes());
    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);
    document.add(new Paragraph("\n"));
}
document.close();

long end = System.nanoTime();
System.out.printf("Created %s with %d fields in %f seconds.\n", filename.getName(), fieldCount, ((float)end - (float)start) / 1000000000f);
```

*([TimingXmlWorker](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/xmlworker/TimingXmlWorker.java#L44) test `testMakePdfLikeEvanV`)*

The output:

```
Created MakePdfLikeEvanV.pdf with 35 fields in 3.221226 seconds.
```

Furthermore you said

> I've tried collecting all of the HTML strings and putting them in one big string to read from in case the issue was that I was creating several instances of the XMLWorkerHelper to write the InputStream made from the HTML strings however this did not speed up that step.

I tested this as follows:

```java
int fieldCount = 10000;
long start = System.nanoTime();

OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(filename);
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
document.open();
StringBuilder xmlString = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; ++i) {
    xmlString.append("<p>")
             .append(("Value " + i))
             .append("</p>");
}
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.toString().getBytes());
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);
document.close();

long end = System.nanoTime();
System.out.printf("Created %s with %d fields in %f seconds.\n", filename.getName(), fieldCount, ((float)end - (float)start) / 1000000000f);
```

*([TimingXmlWorker](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/xmlworker/TimingXmlWorker.java#L85) test `testMakePdfLikeEvanVSingleWorkerCall`)*

The output:

```
Created MakePdfLikeEvanVSingleWorkerCall.pdf with 10000 fields in 1.610613 seconds.
```

Thus, I cannot reproduce the issue.

The difference in the first case (separate workers for each field) might be explainable if you happen to run the code on a slow computer. But in the second case (single worker for all fields) your observation "no speed up" is completely deviating from my observation that in this case I had to drastically increase the number of "fields" to get a run time above a second.

**Thus, there is a factor you don't mention which is acting as a break.**

- Are you probably storing onto a net file system and the extra time is required for permission checking and transmission?
- Or is the `List<FieldValue> values` you retrieve via `tc.getFieldValues()` actually executing a web service request for each and every `values.size()` and `values.get(i)`?
- Or is `fv.getValue()` executing such a web service request?
- Or...

Comment: I tried using the StringBuilder again this morning after you mentioned that it was much faster when you ran it. I have no idea how it was slower last time for me, but it totally worked this time. The whole document took under a second to write. Thank you for your help.